# Undefined index: file. Tried all other solutions

Tags: php

I have a form upload.php:

```
session_start();
<form action="../../banking/upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="bank">
    <br /><br />
    <label for="file">Select File:</label><br />
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

And I have upload_file.php file:

```
session_start();
$filsuc = 0;
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  $fil = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  if($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 4)
    echo "<div align=center>Please ensure that you pick a file</div>";
  elseif($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 1)
    echo "<div align=center>File is too large, maximum limit is 2MB</div>";
  else
    echo "<div align=center>Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "</div><br />";
  }
else
  {
  $filsuc = 1;
  $fil = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  echo "<div align=center>";
  echo "<br>Thank you, the file has been stored in: " . "upload/" . $fil;
    echo"<br><br><br><input type=button onclick='location.href=\"banking.php?fil=$fil\"' value=\"Click here to continue\">";
    echo "</div>";
    //echo "<br><br>Click <a href=\"banking.php?fil=$fil\">here</a> to continue.";

  }


      move_uploaded_FILES($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $fil);
      echo "<div align=center>";
      echo " <br>OR ";
      echo"<br><br><br><input type=button onclick='location.href=\"upload.php\"' value=\"Click here to go back to start\">";
       if($filsuc == 1)
        echo "<br><br><img src=\"pics/fileuploadblur.jpg\" />";
      echo "</div>";
     // echo "<br><br><br><a href=\"upload.php\">Back to start</a> ";   

}
```

If I comment out `if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))`  I get the error Undefined index: file. Otherwise I get a blank result page. I assume that my data is not pulling through to my upload_file.php file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have write permissions on `upload/` directory?

Comment: Hi, yes I do. The problem is that on my form is not read by my Session variable. Just figured that out.

Comment: The problem appears to be the form submission.  Your form is not being sent correctly, and hence the `isset()` fails.  Is this all the code in the files or are there any other bits? You appear to be missing `<?php ?>` tags etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
move_uploaded_FILES($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $fil);
```

**> change this function to following function**

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $fil);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. But this is unfortunately not working.

Comment: Also, define `$filsuc` in the beginning, it causes error `Undefined variable: filsuc in ...\upload_file.php on line 32` if you hit upload button without selecting a file

Comment: @B-and-P I do have that in my code. Just didn't include it here. But has updated my code.

Comment: I just tested your scripts locally and it works with two edits mentioned above. No errors. How are you testing this? The only way I can replicate your error is to load `upload_file.php` directly instead of submitting to it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try writing**

```
$fil = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

 after 

 if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
```

Comment: generally session variables should be declared before html tag in every page